# socket.io not working on several clients

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm trying to build a simple chat client and am having some issues getting it working across multiple clients. Chances are I've missed something really simple. When I send something from one client it is logged in that client but not in any others.

**Server**:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('send', function (data) {
        socket.emit('receive', data);
    });
});
```

**Client**:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
socket.on('receive', function(data){
    console.log("Data received at " + new Date() + ": " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `socket` variable that gets passed to your callback function is a handle on the client that connected, so `socket.emit` is behaving correctly, i.e. it *should* only send to the client that originated it.

Try:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('receive', data);
```

to send to everybody *except* the originating client, or

```
io.sockets.emit('receive', data);
```

to send to all clients including the originator.

Answer (score 1):

You want to emit on all sockets, not just the one that sent the message.
So you should be using:

```
io.sockets.emit('recieve', data);
```

This is assuming that you aren't logging the data on the sending client before sending it to the server. In that case you'll want to use:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('recieve', data);
```

Which will send the message to all connected clients *except* the sender.

[See here for reference on Socket.io](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/)

*Edit:* Trevor beat me to it. However, for some additional clarification: `io.sockets` is the same as `io.of('')`. Which is handy to know for when you start using namespaces in a scoket.io app.